# use epoch with current date

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this:

```
let today = new Date()
let todayMinusFive = today.setHours(today.getHours() - 5);
```

it is taking the current time and then subtract 5 hours from it to get the time in EST.
logging this will get me an epoch time.

then what i am doing is this:

```
let myTime = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDay(), hour, minute);
```

and what this does is take the current date with my variables of `hour` and `minute` defined in there, which are properly split above. After this, I do this:

```
myTime = Math.floor(myTime / 1000)
```

this again now gives me the epoch time for my time from the database with `hour` and `minute`.

What I then want to do is subtract the two:

```
if (todayMinusFive - myTime <= 5) {
 console.log("doing logic")
}
```

but the problem is it isn't working. i know for a fact that the time difference is less then 5, and it is saying it is this huge number like `16000` or something. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Note that "and then subtract 5 hours from it to get the time in EST" won't actually reliably get you that time, thanks to the magic of daylight saving/standard time switching. It doesn't even reliably get you "the time it was 5 hours ago" because the daylight saving/standard time switches can make that an invalid assumption, too. Use `new Date().toLocaleString('en-US', { timeZone: 'EST' });` instead.

Comment: (where the `en-US` tells JS which date/time formatting to apply, and the timeZone option will take whatever your local time is, and convert it to whatever it currently is in EST)

Comment: ohhh okay yeah that makes sense. Good note, thank you. do you hvae any idea what my other problems may be as well?

Comment: Can you update your post a little to explain what goal you're trying to achieve? (that is, not "I want a time difference" but _why_ do you need that time difference? What property are you trying to determine that will control which code path your program goes down). Just so we can avoid an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) where you're asking about some maths that may turn out to not even be necessary at all.

Comment: If you want to subtract time you should consider using epoch time like:
var now = new Date();
var fiveHoursAgo = new Date(now.getTime() - 18000000); // 5 * 60 * 60 * 1000 = 5 hours in ms

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Basically what I need to do is in my DB, I have a time and a date in which an event takes place. With the event time, I am checking against the current time, and if it was within the last 5 minutes, then execute the logic i have, else, do nothing. Does that make sense?

Comment: Please remember to have that [in your post](/help/how-to-ask) because you're not talking "to me", you're trying to make sure everyone reading your post has the information/details they need to answer it. As for the actual information: just compare "seconds since unix epoch" without timezone considerations? (i.e. save your event times as ```Date.now();``` and then check if they're more than 300 seconds apart. Bearing in mind that this _will_ still go wrong across daylight saving/standard time, which is something that will always need special consideration)